# Embed python code in C++ (Windows + minGW + Python 2.7.2 + Eclipse)

Tags: c++, python, eclipse, embed, mingw

I'm trying to embed python code in `C++ (Windows 7 + minGW + Python 2.7.2 + Eclipse Indigo with CDT and PyDev)`.

So, this is the simple code:

```
#include <Python.h> //Python.h
#include <iostream> //iostream
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
    "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And I couldn't understant what am I doing wrong.
I include dirrctories `C:\Python27\include` and `C:\Python27\lib`s but I can't build my project.

1) When I trying to build my project I got this error:

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               **** g++
-IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\libs -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
-fmessage-length=0 -o main.o ..\main.cpp g++ -o testpy2.exe main.o
main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\const\workspace\testpy2\Debug/../main.cpp:7: undefined
reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
C:\Users\const\workspace\testpy2\Debug/../main.cpp:9: undefined
reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
C:\Users\const\workspace\testpy2\Debug/../main.cpp:10: undefined
reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped Time consumed: 1507  ms.
```

2) And if I change current toolchain in Eclipse from "minGW" to "CrossGCC" .. I got this error:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project testpy ****

make all  Building file: ../main.cpp Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler g++
-I"C:\Python27\include" -I"C:\Python27\libs" -O3 -Wall -c
-fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o"
"../main.cpp" Finished building: ../main.cpp   Building target:
testpy.exe Invoking: Cross G++ Linker g++  -o "testpy.exe"  ./main.o  
-l"C:/Python27/libs/libpython27.a" -l"C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib"
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lC:/Python27/libs/libpython27.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lC:/Python27/libs/python27.lib collect2: ld returned 1
exit status make: *** [testpy.exe] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong with my code or settings or something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a linker error, not a compiler error. You need to link to the python. As you can see, with the "CrossGCC" toolchain you are almost there:

```
-lC:/Python27/libs/libpython27.a
```

You need to change this to

```
-LC:/Python27/libs -lpython
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but with small changes.. instead -lpython I add -lpython27. Now I got: Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -LC:/Python27/libs -lpython27 -L"C:\Python27\libs" -L"C:\Python27\include" -o "testpy.exe"  ./main.o   -lpython27